# Where clause is not working after multiple table join in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a base table called inventory_base and several other related tables having foreign key at inventory_base. I want to fetch data from all the tables by id present on inventory_base using Laravel Eloquent (Laravel 8)

I wrote the following query

```php
$where = ['base_inventory.id' => (int)$request->id];

$data = BaseInventory::select(
        "base_inventory.id as id",
        "base_inventory.spare_id as spare_id",
        "base_inventory.item_type as item_type",
        "base_inventory.area as area",
        "base_inventory.machine_name as machine_id",
        "base_inventory.item_category as item_category",
        "base_inventory.item_desc as item_desc",
        "base_inventory.location as location",
        "base_inventory.spare_category as spare_category",
        "base_inventory.unit as unit",
        "base_inventory.max_stock_level as max_stock_level",
        "base_inventory.reorder_level as reorder_level",
        "base_inventory.opening_balance as opening_balance",
        "base_inventory.old_id as old_id",
        "base_inventory.unit_price as unit price",
        "base_inventory.created_by as created by",
        "base_inventory.updated_by as updated_by",
        "item_type_base.item_type as item_type_name",
        "area_base.area as area_name",
        "machine_base.machine_name as machine_name",
        "item_category_base.category as item_category_name",
        "base_inventory.item_desc as item_desc",
        "location_base.location as location_name",
        "spare_category.spare_category as spare_category_name",
        "unit_base.unit as unit_name",
        "base_inventory.max_stock_level as max_stock_level",
        "base_inventory.reorder_level as reorder_level",
        "base_inventory.opening_balance as opening_balance",
        "base_inventory.old_id as old_id",
        "base_inventory.unit_price as unit price",
        "users.name as created_by"
    )
    ->join('item_type_base', 'item_type_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.item_type')
    ->join('area_base', 'area_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.area')
    ->join('machine_base', 'machine_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.machine_name')
    ->join('item_category_base', 'item_category_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.item_category')
    ->join('location_base', 'location_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.location')
    ->join('spare_category', 'spare_category.id', '=', 'base_inventory.spare_category')
    ->join('unit_base', 'unit_base.id', '=', 'base_inventory.unit')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'base_inventory.created_by')
    ->where($where)
    ->get();
```

If I execute it it returns no rows. But if i run it without where clauses then it returns matching rows.
I tried printing raw query using `->toSql()`. It shows `where (base_inventory.id = ?)` at the end. Printing `$request->id` displays the passed id without any error. What I am missing? Please help me to find it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: The ? you see are placeholders or bindings for the information which will later be substituted and automatically sanitised by PDO. See the PHP docs for more information on prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: change your where variable to $where = [['base_inventory.id' ,$request->id]];